# Python shows ['variable'] not in index, but 'variable' is in

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I need to read a csv file, so I have the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
```

Ten, if I run

```
data.columns
```

I can see I have columns called "armonia", "letra" and "interprete", with something like that

> Index(['armonia;letra;interprete'], dtype='object')

Then I run `newdata=data[["armonia","letra"]]` and I get the following error:

> KeyError: "['armonia' 'letra'] not in index"

Precided by that:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-f1fc72f6385b> in <module>()
----> 1 nuevoss=nuevos[["armonia","letra"]]
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2131         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2132             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2133             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2134         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2135             return self._getitem_frame(key)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_array(self, 
key)
   2175             return self._take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2176         else:
-> 2177             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2178             return self._take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2179 
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in 
_convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1267                 if mask.any():
   1268                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1269                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1270 
   1271                 return _values_from_object(indexer)
```

I know "armonia" and "letra" are in index, the .columns command proves that.
I saw a guy having a very similar problem in github and reporting a bug in pandas, but that solution didn't work for me [Very similar problem resolved](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17275)

May someone know if I'm doing something wrong? I'm a very rookie but I've loaded CSV files in python before and worked with them.
¡Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your index is showing you that it contains a single column, with the column name `'armonia;letra;interprete'`. This is because by default [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) assumes your separator is a comma, not a semi-colon. You can fix this by properly specifying your separator:

```
data = read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: @AlejandroMarín Glad I could help, I appreciate the effort in your question.